# MySQL Create Table Error - Table Doesn't Exist

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, and I am having a problem where if I try to create a Table in my newly created Database "recommend", I get the following error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'recommend.Users' doesn't exist

I checked related posts here and on the internet but nothing helped. 
If I use the MySQL command line I still get the same error.

```
SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL;

+------------+

| DATABASE() |

+------------+

| recommend  |

+------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but then  when i run this command :

```
mysql> use recommend
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE Users (UserName VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),PRIMARY KEY(UserName));
```

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'recommend.Users' doesn't exist

I also tried using Navicat and still get the same error :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a data dictionary problem. You can get more information by checking the error log. (See the MySQL docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-log.html)).

Possibly, you have an orphaned table. If so, the solution is to create a table of the same name in a different database, then copy the `.frm` file to the current database. Then you can `DROP` the table, and a subsequent `CREATE` should then succeed. More details on troubleshooting this sort of problem can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html)

Comment: I just uninstalled mysql server and dropped the old Tables, fixed this issue now.

Comment: Thanks a tonns for the help :) Cheers :)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. I actually read this thread before I got lucky with a simple solution. I attempted to drop my table and it worked, in your case your table is User:

> DROP TABLE Users;

The table does not exist, so naturally MySQL complains:

> Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'Users'

But then I ran my CREATE TABLE statement again and it worked. Hopefully others can validate this works every time? A lot easier than going to an error log, especially if you are not the greatest DBA/System Admin/Hacker.

Comment: Much easier than mucking around in the file system!  Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me as well. An elegant way in case you don´t care about a table  data backup.

Comment: Works also for me, if it doesn't work for you try writing the DROP command before the CREATE command in the same script.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was...
You have a DB with "InnoDB ENGINE"....... 
My Solution was...
You must have a "MyISAM ENGINE", 
how to change?...  find on your environment may be with

```
# find / -name my.cnf
```

on LINUX, simply add the following line to

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add:

```
default-storage-engine= MyISAM
```

Then restart mysql:

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: this worked. thanks so much. but i didnt change it in my conf. added in query only